# Issues with ES6 import/ from syntax

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

i have created an app which i am running it on my windows pc and works fine. is a MERN application now i have seted up a machine with ubuntu so i can serve it. but i cant run the back end i have the following error:

> import mongoose from "mongoose"; ^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32) at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3) at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12) at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19) at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)`

all node modules are installed,
node installed 10.19.0,
npm installed,
mongo db installed,
nodemodules installed,
"type":"module" is on json file:

```
{
  "name": "myidea",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "npx nodemon index.js",
    "seed": "node db/seeds.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.5",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^3.1.0",
    "multer-gridfs-storage": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

But still when i do `npm run serve` or `npm run seed` i have the error above. what em i missing here?

i have tried npm run serve and npm run seed and still i am getting the same error despite the fact ii have added the "type":"module" on the json

Comment: What does `node --version` return on your ubuntu server? This error indicates your node version might be outdated (which happens pretty often when you install it from the distribution's package repository). Install a recent version of nodejs

Comment: @derpirscher  node version is 10.19.0

Comment: Well, 10.x is out of maintenance for nearly 2 years now. Current LTS is 18.x. ES6 modules via `"type": "module"` setting in package.json was introduced in 12.x. So again: Install a recent version of nodejs, because this is issue you are seeing now is probably only the first of many more to come, because certain features are not supported in you ancient version of the runtime.

Comment: @derpirscher man you have saved me! i have used the v15.10.0 and worked!! u saved me! thank you so much!!

Comment: If your ubuntu server is some sort of production environment I strongly suggest to use the current LTS version (ie 18.x). Furthermore all odd version numbers (13, 15, 17, 19 ...) are considered development version and should not be used in production environments ...

Comment: @derpirscher i didnt know all these!! thank you!! i will ubgrade to 18.xx i am using ubuntu desktop as a server for now i think is eaasier to config and mess around rather than the server